# Java: force annotation near another annotation on compile time

Tags: java, annotations

Is there any way to force an annotation on another annotation on compile time?

My goal is to force "Programmer B" whenever he/she declares an annotation, to declare another annotation

So following the example below, if programmer B, declared above a method Annotation1, he must declare beneath or above it, Annotation2

code example:

```
@Annotation1
@Annotation2
public void method(){}
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own annotation like this:

```
@Annotation1
@Annotation2
public @interface CustomAnnotation {
}
```

And then use `@CustomAnnotation` combining two of annotations

Comment: I like your approach, is there a way to pass parameters into CustomAnnotation and then to annotation 1 and 2?